# jQuery animate working with one event but when second event added they are not working

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZEewV/

When using the north event, the animate works with the object. When I add the second animate neither of the two work. I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
$("#north").click(function () {
    $(".char").animate({
        top: '-=10px'
    }, 500);
});

$("#south").click(functon() {
    $(".char").animate({
        top: '+=10px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Gee, it's not `functon`, but `function` -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZEewV/1/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a common typo


Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your second function. It should read `function` not 'functon' fix that and it will work.

Comment: +1, there you go, cheap points!

Comment: Wow.. Sorry for wasting your time! Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#north").click(function () {
    $(".char").animate({
        top: ($(this).position().top - 10) + "px"
    }, 500);
});

$("#south").click(function() {
    $(".char").animate({
        top: ($(this).position().top + 10) + "px"
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I don't understnd why it would not work.

Comment: This copied your error, it still says **functon**, so it's not really an answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice his error. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled 'function' as 'functon'.